# non existing url path throws standard IIS 404 page

Tags: asp.net, web-config

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iis 7.5 hijacking 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335846/iis-7-5-hijacking-404)

I'm running a .net 4.0 site over a IIS 7.5.

I have added the custom errors section to my webconfig:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="/error" mode="On">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="/error?code=404"/>
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="/error?code=500"/>
    </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

The custom errors are working. Any internal server errors are redirected to `/error?code=500` and any `throw new HttpException(404, "Not found")`, when a missing parameter is found, are redirected to `/error?code=404`. But any non existing url path still throws the standard IIS 404 page, not my custom 404.

Any tip?

Answer (score 2):

That happened to me once in IIS 7, the solution was to configure the IIS-Application error pages:

- Open IIS
- Select your applciaiton
- Open Error Pages under the IIS section
- In the right panel named Actions, click Edit Feature Settings
- To test choose:

  - Custom Error Pages
- Accept the changes
- Restart IIS

That did the trick in my case

### Edit 1

Remember that the `customErrors` section works **only for requests handled by ASP.Net** the static requests like html pages will still redirect to the 404 error page configured in IIS

However, you could override this behavior in your own config file:

[For more info](http://tedgustaf.com/en/blog/2011/5/custom-404-and-error-pages-for-asp-net-and-static-files/)

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="Replace" errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="GenericError.aspx" responseMode="Redirect"  />
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

You also might need to mark the above section as *updatable*:

Open the file:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
```

And change:

```
<section name="httpErrors" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
```

To:

```
<section name="httpErrors" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

Comment: This post is not correct. The customError section works for classic asp as well as ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it in Global.asax or in IHttpModule.

```
Exception currentException = Server.GetLastError();
HttpException httpException = currentException as HttpException;
if (httpException != null && httpException.GetHttpCode() == 404)
{
    // redirect
}
```

Check http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/508/wildcard-script-mapping-and-iis-integrated-pipeline/ for info how to setup wildcard mapping, so all requests are handled by asp.net.

Comment: Handle all non existing urls? how?

Comment: I tried to put the piece of code inside the application error but the IIS seems to hijack the user if a non existing path is accessed, because the code doesn't fire.